# Snappy file in unix decompress using unix commands

Tags: snappy

how to decompress snappy format file in unix using unix commands. from Amazon s3 files are ftped to unix, i want to convert these files to orc format. can anyone help me with how to decompress snappy format file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on unix.se

Comment: Hi, can you help with the unix command. Thanks in advance,  i have searched and not find proper solution on this.

Comment: You might have better luck posting this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ than here on SO.